# php and datatable row delete/update

Tags: jquery, datatable, auto-update

I use DataTable to display table here is a code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').dataTable( {
        "iDisplayLength": 50,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
     "bStateSave": true
} );
} );
</head>
<body>
             <table class="display" id="example">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th class="id-th"><strong>ID</strong></th>
                <th class="date-th"><strong>Date Added</strong></th>
                <th class="fullname-th"><strong>Full name</strong></th>
                <th class="email-th"><strong>Email</strong></th>
                <th class="visits-th"><strong>Visits</strong></th>
                <th class="totalleads-th"><strong>Total Leads</strong></th>
                <th class="uniqueleads-th"><strong>Unique Leads</strong></th>
                <th class="unpaid-th"><strong>Unpaid Leads</strong></th>
                <th class="action-th"><strong>Actions</strong></th>
              </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php$query = "SELECT * FROM publishers";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$publisher_id = $row['id'];
$publisher_datetime = $row['date_time'];
$publisher_firstname = $row['first_name'];
$publisher_lastname = $row['last_name'];
$publisher_email = $row['email']; ?>
                <tr class="">
                <td class="id-th"><strong><?php echo $publisher_id; ?></strong></td>
                <td class="date-th"><strong><?php echo $publisher_datetime; ?></strong></td>
                <td class="fullname-th"><strong><?php echo "$publisher_firstname $publisher_lastname"; ?></strong></td>
                <td class="email-th"><strong><?php echo $publisher_email; ?></strong></td>

                <td class="visits-th"><strong><?php echo $publisher_visits; ?></strong></td>
                <td class="totalleads-th"><strong><?php echo $publisher_total; ?></strong></td>
                <td class="uniqueleads-th"><strong><?php echo $publisher_unique; ?></strong></td>
                <td class="unpaid-th"><strong><?php echo $publisher_unpaid; ?></strong></td>
                <td class="action-th">
                    <ul class="button-table-head">
                        <li><div class="button-head edit-icon"><a href="#" class="sweet-tooltip" data-text-tooltip="Edit" data-style-tooltip="tooltip-mini-slick"><span>Edit</span></a></div></li>
                        <li><div class="button-head delete-icon"><a href="#" class="sweet-tooltip" data-text-tooltip="Delete" data-style-tooltip="tooltip-mini-slick" onclick="jConfirm('Are you sure you want to delete this publisher?', 'Delete publisher', function(r) {
        jAlert('Publisher deleted');
    });"><span>Delete</span></a></div></li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
              </tr><?php } ?></tbody></table>
```

So now my question is - when I edit or delete row - do I have to RELOAD page each time in order for update to show ? I tried reading the instructions on DataTable, but I really don't understand it.

Thanks for tips !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pure PHP, then **yes**.

If you are open to other methods, like calling PHP scripts with AJAX, then **no**:

Make a PHP scripts that updates/adds/removes data from the DB, and make another script that retrieves the required data from the DB. You can call both kind of scripts as much as you like with AJAX, and keep using the retrieve-data script (again called with AJAX) to display the updated data.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a jquery ajax call for deleting a row and refresh the datatables to show proper pagination and proper records.
I ve searched many methods to refresh data table but the function which i finally made use of does everything you want.
function takes the row no. as the input to perform delete row operation and refresh data table.
This is what i did.

while creating table in for loop. assign no. from 0 onwards as id of tr.
>

```
<script>
    table = $('#table_id').datatables();
    $(delete_row).click(function(){
     ..
     var row_no=$(this).closest("tr").attr("id");
     $.ajax({
        ...
        success : function(data) {
        ...
        table.fnDeleteRow(row_no);
     }
     });
     });
</script>
```